MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots in Docker compose
I have an error in my docker container celery

MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots in Docker compose

I read these answers
MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots and
docker: MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots
Checked free space on my server
docker system df 
TYPE            TOTAL     ACTIVE    SIZE      RECLAIMABLE
Images          10        5         5.506GB   3.416GB (62%)
Containers      7         3         180.2MB   65B (0%)
Local Volumes   50        1         1.988GB   1.738GB (87%)
Build Cache     5         0         0B        0B

df -h --total
total                 155G   27G  124G  18%


Solution from this site  https://zaiste.net/os/unix/howtos/howto-resolve-redis-misconf-error/ states that I should
Set vm.overcommit_memory to 1 in the /etc/sysctl.conf:

vm.overcommit_memory=1
And then, restart the ~sysctl~ process:

sudo sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf

How can I do these actions in my docker-compose infrastructure?
My docker-cmpose.yaml
version: '3.3'

services:
  django:
    image: myhost/main-app:latest
    command: sh -c "
      sleep 3 && gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 core_app.wsgi"
    volumes:
      - ./project/static:/project/static
      - ./project/media:/project/media
      - ./project/logs:/project/logs
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    depends_on:
      - db


  db:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    volumes:
      - pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    expose:
      - 5432
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.24.0-alpine
    depends_on:
      - django
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./project/static:/var/www/html/static
      - ./project/media:/var/www/html/media
      - ./project/nginx-conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d

  celery:
    image: myhost/main-app:latest
    command: celery -A core_app worker  --loglevel=info --concurrency=15 --max-memory-per-child=1000000
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./project:/usr/src/app
      - ./project/media:/project/media
      - ./project/logs:/project/logs
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
    # environment variables declared in the environment section override env_file
      - DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost 127.0.0.1 [::1]
      - CELERY_BROKER=redis://redis:6379/0
      - CELERY_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379/0
    depends_on:
      - django
      - redis


  celery-flower:
    image: myhost/main-app:latest
    command: celery -A core_app flower --loglevel=INFO --port=9090
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - django
      - redis


  redis:
    image: redis:5-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./project:/usr/src/app
      - ./project/media:/project/media
      - ./project/logs:/project/logs
      - ./redis-data:/data
    ports:
     - "6379:6379"
    restart: always
    sysctls:
      - net.core.somaxconn=65535

volumes:
    pg_data:
    static:

